# Can I use my blog posts for an academic publication?

Tags: publications, plagiarism, self-plagiarism, online-resource, social-media

It is not very clear in the publication guidelines of journals or conferences whether one can post some preliminary data or results online (blog, twitter, facebook, *etc.*), gather feedback, and then edit and publish such results in a journal or conference publication (but in other fields [it has happened](http://artsbeat.blogs.nytimes.com/2012/06/20/lehrer-apologizes-for-recycling-work-while-new-yorker-says-it-wont-happen-again/) with some embarassement).

Can a researcher post a blog-entry, or use twitter, sharing data and results with a journal or conference paper? Would it be considered self-plagiarism?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You'd need to ask the specific journal if they're okay with it.  I suspect many would be, since many other forms of quasi-publication prior to a paper are acceptable.

Comment: thanks: it's this *informality* that worries me slightly

Comment: Discussing your work on social media should be treated no differently than a discussion that happens in the hallway outside of your office or in a video conference. Journals can't and won't forbid all manner of prior communication, otherwise they would never be able publish anything.

Comment: _should be treated no differently_ — Yes, it should.  That's doesn't mean it **is**.